# Fragment in Android for MediaPlayer getting null pointers?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, nullpointerexception, android-mediaplayer

I have this code:

```
    Button one = (Button)getView().findViewById(R.id.button_audio);
    final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), R.raw.idontlike);
    one.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

        public void onClick(View v) {
            mp.start();
        }
    });
```

I'm getting this error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.View.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference
```

Comment: Seems like getView() is returning null, so getView().findViewById is throwing the error. Can you post the complete code?

Comment: @zon7 Sorry it's NDA

Comment: Full method code. With only that we cannot know where are you? Is a constructor? another method? is a View? Fragment?

Comment: If this code is in fragment then you can use the view object instead of getView() that is created by inflating the layout.

Comment: @sanjeetkumarSingh what would that look like in context?

Answer (score 0):

You need to search in the fragment layout so try the following

```
View myView= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
Button one = (Button) myView.findViewById(R.id.button);
```